# Where is the qdoc executable?

Tags: qt, qdoc

Seems like I just can't find the QDoc executable.

I downloaded Qt 5.11.1.

Do I need to download QDoc separately?

I checked the docs, but all it says is:
To run qdoc from the command line, give it the name of a configuration file:
`$ ../../bin/qdoc ./config.qdocconf`

Which doesn't help much for finding the file itself.

Comment: Look in the folder where you installed Qt, there must be a folder called bin and in it there must be that executable, you could indicate from where you installed Qt

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that.

Comment: you could indicate from where you installed Qt

Comment: do not search in the folder mingw53_32, search in another folder since that folder only saves binaries of compiled mingw, not of the tools

Comment: On my machine (Windows, MSVS 2017): `C:\Qt\Qt5.11.1\5.11.1\msvc2017_64\bin`

Comment: i have the exact same place, except it's mingw53_32 instead of msvc2017_64, but it's not there. I'll run MaintenanceTool.exe. Maybe I did not install it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using mingw: that build of Qt is missing qdoc for MinGW builds.

See https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.11.1_Known_Issues and https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68064.

You'll need to download qdoc from source and build it (or use an older version potentially).